# Change factor to a date format in R

Tags: r, date

I have a file with dates in the format `YYYY-mm`. I am trying to prepare my data for a time series analysis and therefore need to convert the formats from factor to a `Date` format.

What I've tried:

```
x <- '2011-11'
as.Date(as.character(a), "%Y-%m")
```

the last line gives me an output `NA`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"2011-11" is not a date (where's the *day*)?  Either add a day:

```
a <- '2011-11'
as.Date(paste0(a,'-01'))
```

or use zoo's `yearmon` class:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(a)
```

Comment: It's true, it's not a date. It's a year-month format. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

'2011-11' isn't a date. Use `paste(your.year.month.strs, '01', sep='-')` to add the day component to your strings, then call `as.Date` with `"%Y-%m-%d"`.