# as.Date returning NA in R even after setting C locale

Tags: r, date, na

I am trying to convert string variables written as "Mon-YY" into the date class using as.Date, but I am getting a string of NAs. I used the following code:

```
cal_month = c("Feb-12", "Mar-12", "Apr-12", "May-12", "Jun-12", "Jul-12", "Aug-12", "Sep-12", "Oct-12")
test_Date = as.Date(cal_month, "%b-%y")
```

I got the following output for test_Date:

```
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I saw that there was some previous discussion about setting my C locale, so I did the following, but it made no difference. I got the exact same output as above.

```
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")

cal_month = c("Feb-12", "Mar-12", "Apr-12", "May-12", "Jun-12", "Jul-12", "Aug-12", "Sep-12", "Oct-12")
test_Date = as.Date(cal_month, "%b-%y")

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
```

Comment: Your months need to have a day in order to be a date.

Comment: The **zoo** package has facilities for dealing with year-month data. But without a day, as mentioned, what you have isn't a date.

Comment: And [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252989/change-factor-to-a-date-format-in-r/11253097#11253097) or [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386091/formatting-month-abbreviations-using-as-date/13386510#13386510)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. Your responses were very helpful. The zoo package works very well. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

A date must have a day number.